# How are all three languages Python, Scala and Java supported on Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Just wanted to understand runtime of Spark that how it support three languages simultaneously Scala, Python and Java.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are Spark API bindings that target these three languages. There is nothing unusual in that, and more could be added in the future.

Comment: Thank you I think you answered my question

Answer (score 3):

- **Scala** is the native language for Spark
- **Java** Bindings were created that translate scala constructs into Java friendly ones. E.g. some of the collection classes, case classes, and closure structures have to be handled differently in java

  - Java api's run in same jvm as scala: just have different signatures
- **Python** is a bit different:

  - Given it is not a JVM language it runs in a separate process space from Java/Spark
  - py4j is used to communicate between a jvm running spark and the python process
  - python contacts the Java API's (not Scala) - and they in turn invoke native scala api's
  - some operations on data run locally in python - but cluster operations run on the scala side